# Is there a way to set the sliding_up_panel height to be flexibe (e.g. scale to content)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there any way to make the sliding_up_panel height flexible to it's contents.
This is the current situation:

[image: Current situation]

And this would be the preferred situation:

[image: Preferred situation]

I am using flutter sliding_up_panel 1.0.2.

Here is the relevant code:

```
SlidingUpPanel(
  panel: Flexible(
    child: _answer != null ? AnswerInformationWidget(answer: _answer) : Text(''),
  ),
  controller: _panelController,
  onPanelClosed: _closeAnswer,
  defaultPanelState: PanelState.CLOSED,
  minHeight: 0,
  maxHeight: _slideUpPanelHeight,
  backdropTapClosesPanel: false,
  body: GoogleMap(
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
    scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
    buildingsEnabled: false,
    initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      controller.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
      _googleMapController.complete(controller);
    },
    markers: Set.from(_markers.values),
    circles: Set.from(_circles.values),
  ),
),
```

Comment: can you share the code ?

Comment: Good point, I've attached the relevant snippet. @Niteesh

Comment: can you share the code for AnswerInformationWidget?